# How to append image on running video using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add images on running video using c#.
My Code Is but not working

```
byte[] mainAudio = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(image path));//Upload by User
byte[] intreAudio = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(video path));//File Selected For Interruption

List<byte> int1 = new List<byte>(mainAudio);
int1.AddRange(intreAudio);
byte[] gg = int1.ToArray();

using (FileStream fs = 
    System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath(@"\TempBasicAudio\myfile1.mp3")))
{
    if (gg != null)
    {
        fs.Write(gg, 0, gg.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on running video"? Do you want to overlay images over the film, or do you want to append the images, maybe as a slideshow, at the end?

Answer (score 2):

Did it ever occor to you that a video file is not justa mindless "array of images" so you can not just add another byte range at the end?

Depending on the video type there is a quite complex structure of management structured you just ignore. Videos are highly complex encoding.

YOu may have to add the images in a specific form WHILE UPDATING THE MANAGEMENT INFORMATION - or you may even have to transcode that (decode all images, then reencode the whole video stream).

Maybe a book about the basics of video processing is in order now? You are like the guy asking why you can not get more horsepower out of your car by running it on rocket fuel - totally ignoring the realities of how cars operate.